# Xamarin Forms - Navigate to another page

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin Forms for Android and IOs app.

I have two pages, Login page and Main page.
The  logic I want to implement is: Check if user is Logged In, If no open "Login" page, if yes go to "Main" page.

I was trying to implement this using NavigationPage and Navigation.PushAsync method. But method not working without NavigationPage, and NavigatetionPage renders additional navigation bar at the top.

Now I'm using:

App.xaml.cs

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        if (!isUserLoggedIn)
        {
            MainPage = new LoginPage();
        }
        else
        {
            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
    }
```

LoginPage.xaml.cs

```
//When user authenticated
App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
```

This code works well, but I'm not sure if this is good and correct solution.

Is there any better way to implement same logic?

Comment: You can hide the navigation bar of NavigationPage.  But what you're doing is fairly standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need hide the Navigationbar in your LoginPage and MainPage.

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    if (!isUserLoggedIn)
    {
        MainPage =  new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
    }
    else
    {
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(MainPage());
    }
}
```

LoginPage.xaml.cs:

```
public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    }

//When user authenticated
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(MainPage());
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I see now. But which solution is better?

Comment: Normally we would use NavigationPage.It provides a hierarchical navigation experience where the user is able to navigate through pages, forwards and backwards, as desired.